# how CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID get a value in libevent CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake, libevent

when I compile libevent using cmake, I found some confusing code as follow:

```
if (("${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang") OR
    ("${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "AppleClang"))
    set(CLANG 1)
endif()
if (("${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU") OR (${CLANG}))
    set(GNUC 1)
endif()
if (("${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC") OR (${CLANG}))
    set(MSVC 1)
endif()
```

I'm really confused about where CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID get the value, when I print CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID under centos, it says "GNU"
[CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78cFw.png)

could someone give me a help?

Comment: "where CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID get the value" - The variable [CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html) is set at the `project()` call. During this call CMake detects compilers and obtains their properties. Variable `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID` contains a property of the C compiler.

Comment: yes you're right, a huge thanks for helping.